Can I use uc3843 ic for buck converter for charging of battery from solar panels
I want my solar panels to increase the amp why voltages decrease, so I want a buck converter using uc4843 for my project so I need more information about that

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

18volt input output 13.2 10am
